# Raisin-Problem (Probability)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, stochastic-processes

$M$ raisins are kneaded into an amount of dough, then $N$ bread rolls are made
out of the whole dough. Give a stochastic model for the number
of the raisins in a bread roll. How many raisins should you at least
use so that a bread roll contains with a probability 95% at least one
raisin?

My idea to show that a bread roll contains with a probability 95% at least one
raisin, would be

$P(X\ge 1)=1-P(X=0)\ge0,95$

However I don't know how I sould show this for$M$ raisins and $N$ bread rolls..

(Another Idea would be:
$P(X\ge 1)=1-P(X=0)\ge0,95=$

$=1-q^M\ge0,95$

$=q^M\le0,01$

$=M*ln(q)\le ln(0,01)$

$\to M\ge \frac{ln(0,01)}{ln(q)}$
but that doesn't seem right.

Would be very helpful, if someone could help me here!

Answer (score 2):

In order to do proper modeling, one would have to know the approximate
sizes of $M$ and $N.$ The question does not give any clue. And your
proposed answer doesn't help much. (Finally, are we talking about a randomly
chosen roll, or do we want to make sure *every one* of the $N$ rolls
has at least one raisin?)

Suppose $M = 1000$ and $N = 200.$ Then there would 5 raisins per roll on average.

The actual number of raisins in a randomly
chosen roll might be modeled as $X \sim \mathsf{Pois}(\lambda = 5).$

That would give $$P(X \ge 1) = 1 - P(X= 0) = 1 - e^{-5} = 0.9933,$$ and
we have enough raisins in the batch to satisfy your condition. It seems
easy to figure out the stingiest $\lambda = M/N$ that would suffice for
a probability of 0.95. Maybe about $\lambda = 3$ would be enough to
keep you safe from the Raisin Enforcement Squad of the local police
department.

For smaller numbers of raisins and rolls you would probably want to
use a binomial or hypergeometric model.

Comment: Sadly it isn't mentioned if we want to make sure every one of the N rolls has at least one raisin, so I assume we are talking about a randomly chosen roll. And yeah I think it's weird that there are no approximated sizes given for M and N.